# Inheritance for ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I am trying to properly set up my classes and learning how to use inheritance properly.  Using MVC 5, entity framework and the identity models to do this.  I have two users that I want to register from different pages (merchants and followers).  I would like to inherent the ApplicationUser but confused on how that inheritance works because ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser.

I want to be able to access the email and userName fields in IdentityUser for registration purposes.  So when creating my Merchant and Follower classes do I inherit AppUser or IdentityUser?

App User Class:

```
    namespace IdentitySample.Models
```

{

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
    }
```

Identity Class:

```
    namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
    {
// Summary:
//     Default EntityFramework IUser implementation
//
// Type parameters:
//   TKey:
//
//   TLogin:
//
//   TRole:
//
//   TClaim:
public class IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>
        where TLogin :      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
    where TRole : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole<TKey>
    where TClaim : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
{
    // Summary:
    //     Constructor
    public IdentityUser();

    // Summary:
    //     Used to record failures for the purposes of lockout
    public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Navigation property for user claims
    public virtual ICollection<TClaim> Claims { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Email
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     True if the email is confirmed, default is false
    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     User ID (Primary Key)
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Is lockout enabled for this user
    public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     DateTime in UTC when lockout ends, any time in the past is considered not
    //     locked out.
    public virtual DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Navigation property for user logins
    public virtual ICollection<TLogin> Logins { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The salted/hashed form of the user password
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     PhoneNumber for the user
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     True if the phone number is confirmed, default is false
    public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Navigation property for user roles
    public virtual ICollection<TRole> Roles { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A random value that should change whenever a users credentials have changed
    //     (password changed, login removed)
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Is two factor enabled for the user
    public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     User name
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
    }
```

Comment: You should tell us a little bit about the intended differences between Merchant and Follower in your application domain.  I cannot be sure with the limited information so far, but this may be better modeled using Roles of Merchant and Follower attached to user accounts rather than subclasses.  But it depends on the requirements of your app.

Comment: I thought about using roles but think that would be unnecessary. Merchant is going to be just created the merchant page and managing a merchants menu items.  Follower is going to be a customer who follows a merchants menu items.

I guess my question boils down to if I inherit Application User does that mean it also inherits Identity User?

Comment: @JPHochbaum You're missing Davids point, modeling two different ApplicationUser classes might be overkill. Unless a Merchant holds different info than a Follower, you could use AppUser for both, apply roles to each and go from there without the headache.

Comment: Yeah a Merchant will hold much different info than a Follower.  Follower is only going to have name, email, phone number.

Merchant will have address, menuItem array, etc....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply inherit from ApplicationUser class, so you will have the following:

```
public class Merchant : ApplicationUser{ //...}
public class Follower: ApplicationUser{ //...}
```

Now, both Merchant  and Follower inherit all properties from both IdentityUser and ApplicationUser.